# Install Several Flatpak Simultaneously

Tags: software-installation, flatpak

If I want to install GIMP and Peek Flatpaks as one command can I enter this?

`flatpak install --user https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/com.uploadedlobster.peek.flatpakref`

Or do I have to install them as two separate commands?

`flatpak install --user https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref`

followed by:

`flatpak install --user https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/com.uploadedlobster.peek.flatpakref`

Answer (score 1):

You can both install and uninstall lists of multiple flatpak packages in a single `flatpak install` / `flatpak uninstall` command by separating each flatpak package in the command with a space character.